# Prevent iOS pinch event from registering as a click

Tags: jquery, ipad, events

I have implemented a full screen image viewing gallery in a **web** application. I'll spare you the full details but one of the key interactions is to click on the full screen image to go to the next one. This works fine with click devices, as well as touch devices where a user taps the image. Both are received as click events which I handle in my javascript to load the next image.

As for touch devices (say an iPad), I like that users can pinch to zoom even further into the image. However, when they let go of their pinch gesture (by lifting their fingers), this gesture registers as a click event which will load the next image. Not good, since they wanted to zoom, not go to the next image.

Therefore, I'm searching for a way to handle pinch events and to prevent them from triggering a click event. The pinch gesture should zoom only, and not register as a click.

Does anybody know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use *onmousedown* or *onmouseup* instead of click. If all else fails, you could log the distance travelled between these two events, and if it's over a certain threshold (ie, probably a pinch gesture) then you could ignore it

I'm assuming of course that a pinch registers both *onmousedown* and *onmouseup*, it may not. But if not, you could use whichever event it doesn't register instead of *click*

Answer (score 0):

Apple documentation for handling gesture and touch events
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

The commands you will want to focus on will be touchEnd and gestureEnd. Maybe something like return false on gestureEnd? (I am not a programmer but hopefully this helps get the ball rolling and you will be able to figure it out.)

Good luck!

Comment: he's building a web app, so I'm not sure the apple iOS docs are much good to him...

Comment: They aren't iOS docs. Apple has -webkit docs for handling javascript touch events.

Just read the link I posted, it says right in the link "SafariWebContent".

This has nothing to do with native, Objective-C code that Apple uses for App Store apps.

And it certainly isn't limited to just iOS. It's for any -webkit based browser.